# How does the useState hook work for updating array, even though it's assigned but never used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, onchange

i use useState hook for updating an array being fetched and pulled through redux state, but never actually use it, but it still works and targets the correct value to update? Pretty sure this isn't a duplicate, not sure why it says that.

```
const [featureDesc, setFeatureDesc] = useState('')

 const updateFieldChanged = index => e => {

      
      ideas.idea.feauterList[index].description = e.target.value
      setFeatureDesc([...ideas.idea.feauterList])
      
  }

 

{ideas.idea.feauterList.map((feauterList, i) => 
    
    <InputGroup className="mt-1">
    
  <FormControl as="textarea" type="text" aria-label="With textarea"  value={feauterList.description}  onChange={updateFieldChanged(i)} onBlur={ e => { const {description} = feauterList; updateFeatureDesc(match.params.id, feauterList._id, {description})}} 
    />
    </InputGroup>
  </Form>
  
}
```

No idea why setFeatureDesc works for updateFieldChange even though I never actually use featureDesc anywhere.

Comment: `updateFieldChanged(i)` immediately calls the function, did you mean to do `() => updateFieldChanged(i)` ?

Comment: No it works how i want it to work. I'm wondering why it works when I assign the useState hook with setFeatureDesc, but never actually use featureDesc anywhere.

Comment: Because you _do_ use the `updateFieldChanged` function by calling it when you pass it to `onChange` which then receives its _return value_.

Comment: I'm talking about the  ```setFeatureDesc([...ideas.idea.feauterList])``` inside the ```updateFieldChanged``` function. The function doesn't work without the hook even though i never actually use it.

Comment: Hooks are how react knows to do "change detection" and re-render the screen?

Comment: Sure, but i'm not using or mapping the hook, i'm mapping the state. The hook targets the correct part of the state even though I never refer to it again in the state. I could create any random useState hook, replace ```setFeatureDesc``` with the random one and it still works. It's fine, it works, was just wondering why...